# Why does Scala's type inferencer fail with this set of implicit arguments involving parameterized types?

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit, type-erasure

I would like to define a method parameterized with type `T` that has behavior dependent on what implicit argument can be found of type `Box[T]`. The following code has this method defined as `foo`. When called with `foo[Int]` or `foo[String]` it will without issue return `1` or `"two"` as expected.

Where things get weird is with the method bar. It is defined as returning an `Int`, but instead of `foo[Int]` I have just `foo`. My hope was that the compiler would infer that `T` must be of type `Int`. It does not do that and instead fails:

```
bash $ scalac Code.scala 
Types.scala:15: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value one in object Main of type => Main.Box[Int]
 and value two in object Main of type => Main.Box[java.lang.String]
 match expected type Main.Box[T]
 def bar: Int = foo
             ^
one error found
```

What is causing this error? Replacing `foo` with `foo[Int]` compiles fine. The simpler situation where there is no `Box[T]` type also compiles fine. That example is also below and uses `argle` and `bargle` instead of `foo` and `bar`.

```
object Main extends Application {

  case class Box[T](value: T)

  implicit val one = Box(1)
  implicit val two = Box("two")

  def foo[T](implicit x: Box[T]): T = {
    x.value
  }

  // does not compile:
  // def bar: Int = foo

  // does compile
  def bar: Int = foo[Int]

  println(bar)
  // prints 1

  // the simpler situation where there is no Box type

  implicit val three = 3
  implicit val four = "four"

  def argle[T](implicit x: T): T = x
  def bargle: String = argle

  println(bargle)
  // prints "four"

}
```

What is going on in this snippet that causes this behavior? What about this interaction of implicit arguments, type inference, and erasure is causing problems? Is there a way to modify this code such that the line `def foo: Int = bar` works?

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will have to explain why the type inference mechanism cannot handle that case, but if you are looking to cleanup your code you could probably do this:

```
object Test extends App {

  case class Box[T](value: T)

  implicit val one: Box[Int] = Box(1)
  implicit val two: Box[String] = Box("two")

  def foo[T : Box]: T = implicitly[Box[T]].value  
  val bar = foo[Int]  
}
```

Note that:

1. I removed the type annotation from `bar` so you are really just indicating the type once (just in a different spot than you wanted)
2. I am using `App` instead of deprecated `Application`
3. Using a *context bound* in the type signature of `foo`

Comment: I haven't used context bounds before. I'm not sure if that works in my real situation, but it is certainly an interesting tool to be aware of.

Comment: I tried wrangling context bounds to get my desired behavior and was not able to. My primary goal is to make it so that `foo` does not need `T` specified when used as long as it can be inferred. The context bounds do seem cleaner than the second argument list though.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to [SI-3346](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3346), though there it is implicit arguments to implicit conversions, and here you have a single implicit.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That does seem like it could be related, but I'll have to puzzle over the situation some more.